# How to use those arrows for scaling the cube?

Tags: modeling

[image]

Im following a tutorial but they dont tell you how to bring those arrows in. Can help me how?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the "tutor" is scaling the object.

Press <kbd>S</kbd> (shortcut for "scale") and move the mouse out (to grow), or in (to reduce size).

But you should seriously consider following a "tutorial" that actually explains things... Don't waste your time with videos that don't help you learn.